# Does Petapoco Open / Close connection automatically?

Tags: c#, database-connection, petapoco

I'm creating a C# Win Forms app using PetaPoco as micro ORM, and in all the examples i have found the database is instantiated with a connection string and then for interaction the connection is Open and finally Closed.

But, when i run my app I noticed that my database is already instantiated with the connection string from App.config and that without opening the connection i can query the database.

Thanks

Comment: I have downloaded the Petapoco source code and check that every database query Opens and Close the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Petapoco relies on AdoDB connection pool, so you can safely open and close conections, but AdoDB gives you one of the pool for performance reasons.